# Return a record of single customer when using inner join in ms access

Tags: ms-access-2007, inner-join

I have a table Customer, Item and Receipt Details in my MS Access 2007 Database. I want to generate a query that will return only details of single customer. I tried this query

```
SELECT 
  [Receipt Details].ReceiptID, 
  [Receipt Details].CustomerID, 
  [Receipt Details].EmployeeID, 
  Customer.Name, 
  [Receipt Details].ItemID, 
  Item.Price, 
  [Receipt Details].Quantity, 
  [Receipt Details].[Quantity] * [Item].[Price] AS Total 
FROM 
  Item 
INNER JOIN 
  [Receipt Details]  ON Item.ID = [Receipt Details].ItemID;
```

But it provied repeated output. Any idea how can we make query that will return only single customer record?

Comment: That query includes `Customer.Name` in the `SELECT`, but there is no data source named `Customer` in the `FROM`.  Please double-check your query and make sure you're showing us the actual SQL statement which gives you repeated output.

Comment: @HansUp: Nice catch. I didn't pay any attention to the rest of the query; I just formatted what was there in the first place. I've updated my answer to include this point as well, for future readers (credit for catching it to you added to revision note for posterity as well).

Comment: @KenWhite I'm just kinda OCD WRT SQL.  (enough acronyms for ya?)  Cheers.

Comment: @HansUp: What's scary is I understood them all without having to think about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

With a `WHERE` clause, just like you would any other query:

```
SELECT 
  [Receipt Details].ReceiptID, 
  [Receipt Details].CustomerID, 
  [Receipt Details].EmployeeID, 
  [Receipt Details].ItemID, 
  Item.Price, 
  [Receipt Details].Quantity, 
  [Receipt Details].[Quantity] * [Item].[Price] AS Total 
FROM 
  Item 
INNER JOIN 
  [Receipt Details]  ON Item.ID = [Receipt Details].ItemID
WHERE 
  [Receipt Details].CustomerID = 1234;
```

(`Customer.Name` removed from the SQL above, as you included no `Customer` table in the `FROM` clause. If you actually mean to have it there, add it back, and add that table to the `FROM` with the appropriate `JOIN` condition.)